# Копирование данных нажав на текст

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе определенного текста получалась страница
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Со следующим принципом [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И при нажатии на текст копировалось значение элемента CSS?
Пожалуйста, помогите, не могу разобраться

Comment: Что значит копировались значения элемента css?

Comment: Допустим имеем css со значением shadow, вот чтобы оно копировалось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно:

1. Получить стили элемента. Для этого есть функция [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Например получить ширину блока можно так:

   ```js
   window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#someID')).width
   ```
2. Установить `clipboard` равным `css` коду, который вы получили на 1 шаге. Функцию я взял из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) вопроса на английском stackoverflow. Там же, можете подробней прочитать установки `clipboard`.

В конечном итоге, получил что-то такое:

```js
const block = document.querySelector('#testId');

function copyToClipboard(text) {
    if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.setData) {
        // Internet Explorer-specific code path to prevent textarea being shown while dialog is visible.
        return window.clipboardData.setData("Text", text);
    }
    else if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.textContent = text;
        textarea.style.position = "fixed";  // Prevent scrolling to bottom of page in Microsoft Edge.
        document.body.appendChild(textarea);
        textarea.select();
        try {
            return document.execCommand("copy");  // Security exception may be thrown by some browsers.
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.warn("Copy to clipboard failed.", ex);
            return prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
        }
        finally {
            document.body.removeChild(textarea);
        }
    }
}

const getCSSStyles = (element, styleKeys=null) => {
  const styles = window.getComputedStyle(block);
  const keys = styleKeys === null ? styles : styleKeys;
  const css = keys
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const property = styles.getPropertyValue(curr);
      return `${acc}\t${curr}: ${property};\n`;
    }, '');
  
  // В приоритете id, но если его нет, то берем
  // первый класс, если и его нет, то ничего
  const selector = element.id !== "" 
    ? `#${element.id}` 
    : (element.classList.length > 0 
       ? `.${element.classList[0]}` 
       : "");
  return `${selector} {\n${css}}`;
}

block.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Список стилей для копирования
  const availableStyles = ['box-shadow', 'width', 'height', 'color'];
  copyToClipboard(getCSSStyles(block, availableStyles));
});
```

```html
<div id="testId" class="testClass testSecondClass" style="color:red">
    Block
</div>
```